# Rotating Map in Direction Moving in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, location, direction

I don't know if I am just searching for the answer using the wrong set of words or what but I am trying to make a map app in Android that will show and track your location.  Which works just fine however, I would like to add in the functionality to make it so that the top of the map is the direction you are moving rather than North.  What do I need to do to make this happen?

Thanks